# Using ASP.NET MVC form-group with dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

How to make an dropdown list in form-group with method="post"?
The list has to be dynamic, and the parameter send has to be something else from what is shown in label. I was trying something like this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Product.Category">Choose category:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="Product.Category">
@foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
{
            <option>category.CategoryName</option>
}
        </select>
    </div>
```

But it doesn't work for me, and I have to send to controller the category Id not category name.

The goal is that:

User selects category from dropdown list, and the Id of category is being send to controller.

Comment: because I dont know how, thats why I ask for a solution

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="@category.Id">@category.CategoryName</option>
```

Comment: the value is always null, could you help me?